# Xcode compile source code twice during Build & Run

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working with Xcode as IDE for some years. Suddenly a question brings up in my mind.

In an Xcode iOS app project/workspace, when I execute "Build" (Cmd+B) with my physical device set to be the target, the source code is compiled once.

Then when I execute "Run" (Cmd+R) or press the "Play" button on the top left corner **without modifying any source codes**, Xcode compiled the source codes all over again.

My question is, I would like to know what is the cause of the 2nd compile of the source code. Suppose it does not require 2nd compile, as the target & the source codes remain unchanged.

Comment: How do you know it's doing this; from looking at the build log?

Comment: Since the workspace requires quite lengthy compile time, I noticed it from the progress bar of the Xcode (top center). It goes over the build process all over again.

Comment: Well checkout the build log as that tells the whole story in detail.

Comment: From the build log, the "Build" and "Run" look almost the same.